# Handling mass cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

I have a website that users create their own tasks to be run at a specific time.

At the moment, when the user clicks create task it will add to the database table 'tasks'.

I then have a cron job, which runs every 15mins. It gets all the entries in the table and checks first whether it has been run today using the date time. (every midnight, another cron runs through and resets all these values). If it has not ran this day, it will then run it and afterwards change the value to ran.

The cron job does this by running  php file on my server that checks for tasks, and then uses a simple foreach statement.

At the moment, there are only 11 users and my server seems fine. I am wondering what will happen with lets say 10,000 users.

Is this an efficient way to handle thousands of cron jobs? How yould you go about running this?

Comment: I would run it on AWS Lambda. Send the tasks when they need to go to a Lambda function with a low memory allocation and just run it that way. You can use the request library to call URLs that need to get called. Lambda is pretty much infinitely scalable. By default they let you handle 100 concurrent requests.

Comment: i dont see why you need a 'ran' value or a reset (but a separate logging table would not be a bad idea), you can just check for every task due to run in the previous 15 minutes with a query.

Comment: Maybe you should simulate such situation? It would be interessting to see how CRON calculate massive amounts of expressions.